# What is the difference between HttpContext.Request.Form.Files and action parameter

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-core, dropzone.js

What is the difference between the following methods?

This

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Upload()
{
    var files = HttpContext.Request.Form.Files;

    // Process files

    return Ok();
}
```

and this

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Upload(ICollection<IFormFile> files)
{
    // Process files

    return Ok();
}
```

It seems that [ng-dropzone](https://github.com/thatisuday/ng-dropzone) works with the first variant only.

Comment: Files in HttpContext is declared as `IFormFileCollection` not as `ICollection<IFormFile>`. Have you tried your second approach using `IFormFileCollection` as the parameter type?

Comment: @Daniel J.G. Yep. It doesn't wok with `ng-dropzone` either

Comment: You will also need to add a `[FromBody]` attribute to the parameter as in `Upload([FromBody]IFormFileCollection files)` so the model binder looks a t anything coming from the body. Not sure if that would be enough for it to bind the files